# JavaFX: modify button text in real time

Tags: java, button, javafx

I have a button with a ContextMenu which contains a `MenuItem rename`.
rename.setOnMouseClicked is supposed to give the possibility to change the text in the button : The user can actually delete a letter in the text or write it then press enter to validate what he was typing, somehow working as textField.

**Is it possible to do this ? if so, how can i ? Thanks!**

Comment: Would a call to the `button.setText(String)` method not work? This is a suggestion to the headline question "can I modify button text", which I'm not sure is the same question as the one in the body.

Comment: no the button.setText is working, but what i want to do is modifying the text while the program is already open. so for example the user on the button itself can modify the text as he's dealing with a TextField, the Enter button will call `button.setText(String)` to validate what the user is typing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**

Here's how:

```
public class EditableButtonApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        root.setCenter(new EditableButton("Editable Button"));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    class EditableButton extends Button {
        TextField tf = new TextField();

        public EditableButton(String text) {
            setText(text);
            setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
                tf.setText(getText());
                setText("");
                setGraphic(tf);
            });

            tf.setOnAction(ae -> {
//              if (validateText(tf.getText())) {// this is where you would validate the text
                setText(tf.getText());
                setGraphic(null);
//            }
            });
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Comment: i'll be trying it and validate after it's working ! Thanks a lot !